# In pgfplots, how does one fill the gap near zero of a symmetric graph?

Tags: pgfplots

I am drawing a simple graph of the equation `9x^2=x+4`, therefore two plots are being drawn on `sqrt(x+4)/3` and `-sqrt(x+4)/3`.

During draft compilations, I use 40 samples, and during final compilations 400. Using 40 samples yields are large gap; larger sample counts provide smaller gaps, but there is a limit to the number of samples that can be calculated.

What method am I overlooking to fill that gap between the two `\addplot` commands?

```
%%% mwe.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[
        samples = 400,
        thick,
    ]
    {sqrt(x+4)/3)};
    \addplot[
        samples = 400,
        thick,
    ]
    {-sqrt(x+4)/3)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$9y^2=x+4$. How does one fill the gap at $(-4,0)$?}
\label{fig:c02f08}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the default domain, which is `-5:5`. With an even number of samples you will not get a value for x=-4. You can either use for example `samples=401`, or `samples=400,domain=-4:5`. The latter is perhaps better, so `pgfplots` doesn't have to discard the values when trying to calculate square roots of negative numbers.
(When `pgfplots` does encounter something like sqrt(-1) it will print a warning in the log file. These warnings can be turned off with `\pgfplotsset{filter discard warning=false}`, but in this case it's better to just set an appropriate domain I'd say. You can read more about the handling of unbounded coordinates in section 4.5.13
*Interrupted Plots* of the manual.)

What I mean by the number of samples, is that if you have 10 samples from -5 to 5, then the distance between values will be 10/9, so you get one sample at -5, and the next at about -3.9. The same applies for larger numbers of samples.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[
        samples = 400,domain=-4:5,
        thick,
    ]
    {sqrt(x+4)/3)};
    \addplot[
        samples = 400,domain=-4:5,
        thick,
    ]
    {-sqrt(x+4)/3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$9y^2=x+4$. How does one fill the gap at $(-4,0)$?}
\label{fig:c02f08}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To make the MWE, I had removed the domain, but as you demonstrated in your answer, I had chosen ineffective values. My revision uses a domain of -5:5, 41 samples in draft and 801 samples for final. Perfect!

Comment: @kpo7057 If you're worried about compiling speed you should check out the `external` library. Also, as I mention having a domain that runs below -4 is pointless in this case, as you get negative values in the square root.

Comment: During draft compilations (41 samples) using the domain of -5:5 there were eight entries in the log file of the form NOTE: coordinate (2Y5.0e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (
in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). With larger samples, almost 22K of log file size increase occurred. Changing the domain to -4:5 eliminated all log entries of the form presented here.

Comment: @kpo7057 Yes pgfplots is telling you that it drops all the points where you get roots of negative numbers.

Comment: @kpo7057 By the way, if my answer answered your question, consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark to the left. That marks the question as solved.

Comment: I accept(ed) your answer and clicked the arrow: hope it shows! (Newbie afraid to punch buttons when not sure what they do!) How did you attach your image to the post? I would have attached a sample of the mwe to show my trouble visually. I know that it is easier to scan images than reading text when looking for an answer to a specific problem.

Comment: @kpo7057 I took a screenshot and uploaded it via the image upload button found just above the text input field. You need 10 reputation points to add images to posts though.